# Every time the previous data was inserted into database in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to save score and username at end of game in Unity3d. I use PlayerPrefs to get the data. I get username from GUI.TextField. And I insert the data into a mysql database. But every time the previous data was inserted into the database. How can I solve it?

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score",databasescore);
PlayerPrefs.SetString("username",username);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

I use addscore.php and display.php. My HighScoreController.cs is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HighScoreController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string hs;
    public string addScoreURL = "http://localhost:8000/addscore.php?";
    public string highscoreURL = "http://localhost:8000/display.php?";

    void Start()
    {

        StartCoroutine (PostScores (PlayerPrefs.GetString ("username"), PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("score")));
        StartCoroutine (GetScores ());
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
    }

    public IEnumerator PostScores(string username, int score)
    {
                        string post_url = addScoreURL + "username=" + username + "&score=" + score;
                        WWW hs_post = new WWW (post_url);
                        yield return hs_post; // Wait until the download is done

                        if (hs_post.error != null) {
                                print ("THERE WAS AN ERROR GETTıNG THE HıGH SCORE: \n" + hs_post.error);
                        }               
    }

    public IEnumerator GetScores()
    {
        WWW hs_get = new WWW(highscoreURL);
        yield return hs_get;

        if (hs_get.error != null)
        {
            print("THERE WAS AN ERROR GETTıNG THE HıGH SCORE: \n" + hs_get.error);
        }
        else
        {
            hs = hs_get.text;
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("scores", hs);
            Debug.Log(hs);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also show your `PostScores` and `GetScores` functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an algorithmic issue.

GetScores has

```
 PlayerPrefs.SetString("scores", hs);
```

but haven't got,

```
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```